# How to Migrate Multiple TFS Collections from TFS 2010 into a Single Collection on TFS 2015

Tags: version-control, tfs-2015

There doesn't appear to be much literature on the topic (to the point where I'm pretty sure you can't do it)

I see there is this [TFS Integration platform](http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/) (not maintained since March 2012) mentioned in this article http://nakedalm.com/one-team-project-collection-to-rule-them-allconsolidating-team-projects/ but that looks pretty specific for 2012.

Has anyone done this?

Answer (score 2):

This is not a supported scenario.  The TFS Integration Platform can move your data over, but it's not a very smooth experience.

Comment: Is there a recommendation somewhere about what to do?

Comment: @Peter - I think I read somewhere that support for moving Team Projects was coming - although this feature is still unplanned: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2037613-make-it-possible-to-move-a-team-project-between-te